# Accessing external file in aws appsync template mapper

Tags: aws-appsync

Currently, we are using a json file which as a lambda layer. Is it possible to access this lambda layer in appsync template? There will be alot of field in this json file. It is something like this:

```js
module.exports = {
    "INVALID_RFC": {"code": "111", "message": "RFC Code is invalid"}
}
```

I want to access this `INVALID_RFC` property from appsync template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible for AppSync mapping templates.

I ran into a similar problem. My workaround is

- Use placeholders in a mapping template, for example. $INVALID_RFC$
- Write a simple script (NodeJS, Python, or bash) that copies original Velocity templates over a build directory, and also replaces the placeholders with actual values. It's done easily with regular expressions
- Deploy built mapping templates into AWS

Comment: I had a similar feeling. Unfortunately, I'll have to find another workaround This will not enough for use-case